# Error while freeing a malloc'd array of structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I'm having issues freeing a temporary array of structs used for doubling the size of another array.  I don't seem to have any issues freeing the original array.

```
void foo(StruName **structName,i nt *size)
{ 
...
 StruName *temp_array = (StruName*) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(StruName));
 for (i = 0; i < *size; i++)
   temp_array[i] = (*original_array)[i];
 free(*original_array);
 *original_array = temp_array;
 free(*temp_array);
```

I get the following error using g++ -Wall

```
error: cannot convert ‘StruName’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void free(void*)’
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?  If I leave the free(*temp_array); out altogether, the program compiles and runs fine. free(temp_array); causes a segfault

Comment: It would help if you could post the whole program.Anyways, tend to the errors I pointed out.The first line of the function declaration itself has errors.

Comment: Oops, sorry for being unclear. Struct was the name of a typedef struct.  Changed it to StruName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the reason that `original_array` is a pointer to a pointer?

Anyways, it seems to me you shouldn't be freeing the `temp` array as your code snippet seems to imply you're replacing `*original_array` with it.  If that's the case then you are
working with freed memory; this might run fine for a while, but eventually you might find your array values get overwritten, as the freed memory gets reassigned to something else.

```
// here *original_array will be pointing to the new `malloc`ed memory
*original_array = temp_array;

// After this line, *original_array is left dangling to the recently freed memory

free(*temp_array);
```

I would remove that last free line.

*Edit *
I previously mentioned the memory would be freed twice, this is not the case,  as free should have been called without dereferencing *temp_array in order for that to be true.

Comment: Can't tell, your code snippet doesn't contain any reference to a days variable.  Like others have suggested, it would be handy if you posted more code. :)

Comment: Oops, haha.  Read that as free(*original_array) :P  - Thanks.  Is that not doing much since I'm overwriting it anyways?  I've noticed that the program appears to run fine with or without it (nor does valgrind seem to notice).

Answer (score 2):

The following part of function definition is not correct :

```
void foo(Struct **structName, int count, int *size)
```

Have you declared your structure as `structName`? If yes, you need to mention the parameter as well in the definition, not just its type.And even if `structName` is your structure,then you are expected to write `struct structName**` instead of `Struct **structName`.(`Struct` is not the same as `struct` in C)

Here's one more error:

```
malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(original_array)
```

You should enclose `*size` within braces as it's not clear whether you are dereferencing `size` or you are dereferencing the `size*2*sizeof(original_array)`

Answer (score 0):

It's the basic principle of memory use that free what you have allocated. If you free what you haven't allocated, it might cause segmentfault.

The code have allocated the memory with:

```
    StruName *temp_array = (StruName*) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(StruName));
```

Then it should release the memory with:

```
    free(*temp_array);
```

Make sure the content of both parameters are correct.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it seems from the OP code that the value of temp_array is replacing *original_array. If temp_array is freed the *original_array value will be left dangling to freed memory.

Comment: @sgorozco you are absolutely right. It should be really careful with pointer operations, especially in C. And what I'm trying to solve is what Mark asked " If I leave the free(*temp_array); out altogether, the program compiles and runs fine. free(temp_array); causes a segfault"

Comment: I mean, if I free temp_array with free(temp_array);, I get a segfault.  I think this must be because I'm freeing the memory that *original_array is assigned to at the end of the block.

Comment: Using free(*temp_array); must not being doing anything because its incorrectly cast.  Leaving them both out works (and must be the correct thing to do).

Comment: @Mark Yes, the question here is what does original_array mean? We didn't find out the origination of original_array. So I think we'd better take a look or send out a complete simple demo code that can work and debug. what do you think?